# Postfix piping email to php, permissions error

Tags: permissions, ssh, pipe, postfix-mta, permission-denied

I'm attempting to pipe an email to PHP with my Postfix mail server, using the [technique mentioned here](http://www.thevisionworld.com/vision-helpdesk-faqs-exim-postfix-qmail-sendmail-email-piping.html) and have encountered the following error...

```
Mar 16 22:52:52 s15438530 postfix/pipe[9259]: AD1632E84C63: to=<php@[myserver].com>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.61, delays=0.59/0/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: /bin/sh: /var/www/vhosts/[myserver].com/httpdocs/clients/emailpipe/email2php.php: Permission denied 4.2.1 Message can not be delivered at this time )
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this issue for me. I've tried 777'ing the emailpipe directory, to no avail. Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the permissions of the parent of the emailpipe directory (and all directories farther up in the directory structure)? By the way, don't chmod it 777; setting it to 755 is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 10):

From the postfix docs...

> For security reasons, deliveries to command and file destinations are performed with the rights of the alias database owner. A default userid, default_privs, is used for deliveries to commands/files in root-owned aliases.

So you have two options, either set the **default_privs** in main.cf to match the ownership of the email2php file.

Alternatively, there should be a way to create an alias database that is owned by the user instead of postfix/nobody. I haven't tried this before though so can't advise.

Comment: +1. This is likely to be the _actual_ issue causing the perm problem in the first place.

Comment: The down side of the first option is that we can specify only one user to the *default_privs*. So, I tried your alternative solution and got a positive result. See http://serverfault.com/a/517805/145024.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this issue by **disabling the SELINUX**.

Comment: I was able to use the [audit2allow](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html) command to generate a policy that allowed SELinux to remain running but permit my script to handle incoming email piped to it from Postfix.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

(or whatever your path to php is - do "which php" on the server)
at the top of each of your php scripts and that each of the php script files is executable

```
chmod +x /var/.../email2php.php
```

Also, make sure that you can test the script from the command line:

```
cat some_rfc822_email.txt | /var/.../email2php.php
```

and get the result that you want

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you'll want to chown or chmod `/var/www/vhosts/[myserver].com/httpdocs/clients/emailpipe/email2php.php` to executable by your postfix user. Alternately, you'll want to redefine this user to execute the file successfully.

Simply changing the permissions of your *directory* (unless you used `-R`) won't be sufficient.

To illustrate why this works, consider the following toy example:

```
<me>@harley:~$ touch test
<me>@harley:~$ ls -al test
-rw-r--r-- 1 <me> <me> 0 2012-03-26 23:44 test
<me>@harley:~$ sh test
<me>@harley:~$
<me>@harley:~$ ./test
bash: ./test: Permission denied
<me>@harley:~$ chmod 755 test
<me>@harley:~$ ./test
<me>@harley:~$
```

In order to execute a file directly through the running shell, it needs to be set as executable. Other invocations (for example, `sh email2php.php` or `php email2php.php`) only require read access, because they're chaining execution off a different file entirely.

For what's likely to be causing the issue in the first place, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9911679/517815).

Comment: I had used the -R flag, the answer provided by amcnabb allowed me to make progress, however, I'm still encountering issues saving off attachments. Thanks for your suggestion though.